# Buscar números faltantes entre días - Arrays PHP

Tags: php, array

estoy trabajando en este problema y tengo complicaciones.

Tengo un array que contiene 5 fechas diferentes.
Cada fecha, tiene un número inicial, y un número final.
Como dice el título, estoy buscando el modo de saber que números me he saltado entre días y cuales serían las fechas.

En el ejemplo del array, tenemos que:

- Entre el día 1 y el 2, falta el número 24770
- entre el día 4 y el 5, falta entre el 25028 y el 25039

Entonces lo que hago primero, es recorrer el arreglo, y obtener los valores.
Pero lo que no entiendo, es como obtener la fecha anterior y el número anterior para poder continuar.
Además de como le digo al foreach que no inicie en la posición [0] por que tiraría error si obtengo el dia anterior con $i-1 cuando el $i = 0...

```
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $fecha = $a[0];
    $inicial = $a[1];
    $final = $a[2];
    if (NUMEROINICIAL != FINALANTERIOR + 1) { //Se que debo confirmar así después.
        echo "Se ha encontrado un salto entre el día: " . $fechaAnt . " y " . $fecha . "</br>";
    }
}
```

---

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2021-07-01"
    [1]=>
    int(24705)
    [2]=>
    int(24769)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2021-07-02"
    [1]=>
    int(24771)
    [2]=>
    int(24855)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2021-07-03"
    [1]=>
    int(24856)
    [2]=>
    int(24962)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2021-07-04"
    [1]=>
    int(24963)
    [2]=>
    int(25028)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "2021-07-05"
    [1]=>
    int(25039)
    [2]=>
    int(25102)
  }
}
```